# Intersection and union of two strings

Tags: c++

I have to eliminates any occurrence of string 2 in string 1 and also find the intersection of two strings.

Here is what I have tried:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "string.h"

class operation
{
public:
    char string1[100];
    char string2[50];


    operation(){};
    operation(char a[100], char b[50]);
    operation operator+(operation);
    operation operator-(operation);
    operation operator*(operation);
};

operation::operation(char a[100], char b[50])
{
    strcpy(string1, a);
    strcpy(string2, b);
}

operation operation::operator +(operation param)
{
    operation temp;
    strcpy(param.string1, temp.string1);
    strcpy(param.string2, temp.string2);
    strcat(temp.string1, temp.string2);
    return (temp);
}

operation operation::operator -(operation param)
{
    operation temp;
    strcpy(param.string1, temp.string1);
    strcpy(param.string2, temp.string2) ;
    for (int i = 0; i<strlen(temp.string2); i++)
    {
        temp.string1.erase(i, 1);
    }
    return (temp);
}

operation operation::operator *(operation param)
{
    operation temp;
    strcpy(param.string1, temp.string1);
    strcpy(param.string2, temp.string2);
    char result[50];
    for(int i = 0; i<strlen(temp.string2); i++)
    {
        if( temp.string1.find( temp.string2[i] ) != string::npos )
            result = result + temp.string2[i];
    }

    return (temp);

}
```

I am getting compiler errors and also I am not sure what I am trying is correct or not.

The errors are as follows:

```
C2228: left of .erase must have class/struct/union
C2228: left of .find must have class/struct/union
```

Comment: This actually looks like **C++**, and an odd one at that.

Comment: C does not have operator overloading.  Did you mean C++?

Comment: Is this homework?  If so can it be tagged as such?

Comment: The compiler errors you show are in code you haven't listed. I think you probably created your object with `new()` but tried to access your method with `.` instead of `->`.

Comment: Why are you using deprecated C headers? Why not C++ functionality?

Comment: The new "edit" completely changed your original post.  SUGGESTION: Read a bit about C++ std::string and start again: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialC++StringClass.html

Answer (score 9):

Happily, in C++ set [difference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference), [intersection](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection), and [union](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union) algorithms have already been implemented in the standard library. These can be applied to strings like any container class.

Here is a demonstration (you could do this with simple `char` arrays, but I'm using `std::string` for clarity):

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string string1 = "kanu";
    std::string string2 = "charu";
    std::string string_difference, string_intersection, string_union;

    std::sort(string1.begin(), string1.end());
    std::sort(string2.begin(), string2.end());

    std::set_difference(string1.begin(), string1.end(), string2.begin(), string2.end(), std::back_inserter(string_difference));
    std::cout << "In string1 but not string2: " << string_difference << std::endl;

    std::set_intersection(string1.begin(), string1.end(), string2.begin(), string2.end(), std::back_inserter(string_intersection));
    std::cout << "string1 intersect string2: " << string_intersection << std::endl;

    std::set_union(string1.begin(), string1.end(), string2.begin(), string2.end(), std::back_inserter(string_union));
    std::cout << "string1 union string2: " << string_union << std::endl;
}
```

[Run it!](https://ideone.com/IZ8Q2)

How you implement this in your `operation` class is left as an exercise.

Comment: Why you sorted strings before getting their intersection and union?

Comment: @Humoyun because, according to the linked documentation, "Constructs a sorted range beginning at `d_first` consisting of elements that are found in ***both sorted ranges*** [`first1`, `last1`) and [`first2`, `last2`)."

Answer (score 1):

If `strcpy( string1...` compiles then `string1` is a `char*` and not a `std::string`. You seem to be mixing C and C++ functionality for strings. Choose one and stick with it (I'd say `std::string` since you are doing C++)

Answer (score 0):

1. This is C++ (not C: C doesn't have operator overloading)
2. You need to show us your class definition before we can help identify the compile error.
3. If you don't have a class definition for "operator", that alone explains the error :)
4. If you're using C++, you should probably be using standard C++ "string" (instead of C "char []" arrays).  Using "string" will also affect your implementation code.
5. Q: This wouldn't be a homework assignment, would it?
   If so, please add "homework" to your tags.

Thanx in advance .. PSM