# Is there any shorter way of getting an intersection and union of two strings?

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, set

Is there any shorter way of getting an intersection and union of two strings? I was looking for how to get an intersection and union of strings and encountered this answer 
[Intersection and union of two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936654/intersection-and-union-of-two-strings), however, it seems too long for this kind of simple operation, maybe it is because I used to python style (I recently started learning C++). Anyway, I would be very grateful if someone shows me concise way of this.

Comment: What is so long about 2 functions?

Comment: Sorry, but the C++ standard library functions are verbose for a reason. You can always make your own function that takes the input and returns the output how you want

Comment: I don't know how it could be made simpler than the answer you linked tbh.

Comment: You linked a url containing a 1-line solution. That's too long?

Comment: @zeromus yes one line (one long line), std::set_difference(string1.begin(), string1.end(), string2.begin(), string2.end(), std::back_inserter(string_difference)); and it was sorted before intersection

Comment: It sounds like you're having a hard time coming to grips with the level of verbosity of c++. It should help you to know that this is amazingly concise already for c++ and it essentially never gets any more concise than this. Python may come with solve_homework() but c++ comes with pieces_that_help_you_solve_homework()

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the verbosity by using a range library, e.g. Boost.Range. STL is quite verbose because it is based on iterators instead of ranges which essentially are pairs of iterators. With Boost.Range, you can write

```
std::string s1, s2;
std::string difference;
boost::set_difference( boost::sort(s1), boost::sort(s2), std::back_inserter(difference) );
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comments already suggested, no.

Essentially, the "verbosity" of the linked solution is because it's necessary to specify all those arguments in order to be generic. Some common operations have less verbose specific variants (e.g. `string::operator=` is less verbose to use than `std::equal`) but that covers *common* functions. The union of two strings is not a common operation, it's probably used more in homework than anywhere else.